# If $x+(4/x)=4$ then $x^3+(4/x)^3$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x+(4/x)=4$ then  $x^3+(4/x)^3 $is.

Note:
$(x+(4/x))^3=4^3$

assuming $4/x=y$ then

$(x+y)^3=64$

$x^3+y^3+3xy^2+3yx^2=64$

$x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)=64$

$x^3+y^3+3*4(4)=64$

so $x^3+y^3=16$

Comment: Looks good! Also below is an useful formula to memorize $$a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3 - 3ab(a+b)$$

Comment: same formula applied there @ganeshie8

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: to find x^3+(4/x)^3

Comment: But you already did that, so what's the question?

Answer (score 5):

From $x+\frac{4}{x}=4$ we have $x=2$ so that $x^3+(\frac{4}{x})^3=16$